# Prototype of my software in Ubuntu

Tags: xlite

As I mentioned in my last questions I have migrated into Ubuntu some days ago. Before I used Windows 7 and had a software for working with [NGN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_generation_networking). I used it to connect to Telephone Provider and make a call. Only thing I needed is to register in Telephone Provider and get username and password.

But as I am in Ubuntu I can't unfortunately use it. I tried to install and use it in Wine. It has been installed, but when I try make a call it crashes. The name of that software was View OpenEye.

Does anybody know analogue of this software under Ubuntu? I need it so much, so please help a poor linux beginner.

**Update 1**
From my telephone company the recommended me to install [X-Lite](http://www.counterpath.com/x-lite-3.0-for-linux-download.html) application. But once installing it I am getting error `./xtensoftphone: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Does anybody have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: You need to provide some more context here. Do you use some sort of ISDN modem or a router to connect to your provider?

Comment: No, it is only application that using my internet connection connects to my Telephone provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [Twinkle](http://www.twinklephone.com/) and installed it right now. And it is what I wanted. Twinkle is a softphone for your voice over IP and instant messaging communcations using the SIP protocol. You can use it for direct IP phone to IP phone communication or in a network using a SIP proxy to route your calls and messages.
So, I am getting used to Ubuntu step by step finding analogue of all my Win Softs in Ubuntu. 
And I really like Ubuntu. It is great OS.